How to properly connect css files without using css modules in react
The css styles on the page are applied from a file that is not in the import js file
enter image description here
Initially started working with connecting css files with styles separately for each page, is there any way to do without using css modules? Since the styles from the connected css file are not used, there may be inconsistencies between the css files.
enter image description here
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
